# AngularJS ng-submit to intercept form submit

Tags: angularjs

I've just started learning AngularJS and one of my first pages requires intercepting a submit. I'd like to use the **ng-submit** directive but it seems there's something wrong in my code:

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
function MyFormController($scope) {
  scope.add = function(field) {   
    alert(field);
 };
}
</script>
<body>
<div ng-controller="MyFormController">
<form ng-submit="add(field)">
  <input type="text" name="field" ng-model="field" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've added an alter to see if the add function is called, yet nothing is displayed. I guess it must be a silly issue, yet I'm unable to catch it. Any help ? 
 Thanks!

Comment: typo? scope instead of $scope? Next time if you encounter problems like this, first try tro open your chrome dev tools or firebug and watch the console!

Answer (score 0):

You can save the value without the parameter :

```
<script>
function MyFormController($scope) {
  $scope.add = function() {   
    alert($scope.field);
 };
}
</script>

<body>

<div ng-controller="MyFormController">

  <form ng-submit="add()">
    <input type="text" name="field" ng-model="field" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>

</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
<script>
function MyFormController($scope) {
  $scope.add = function(field) {   
    alert($scope.field);
 };
}
</script>
<body>
<div ng-controller="MyFormController">
<form ng-submit="add()">
  <input type="text" name="field" ng-model="field" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```